# Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\IdReader::getIdValue(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type ?object, string given

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a form to manage contacts within a Symfony 6.3 application. Contact creation works well.
However, when I try to modify a contact, instead of the form that would normally show up, there is the following error message:

> Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\IdReader::getIdValue(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type ?object, string given, called in D:\2. TDEKDO\vendor\symfony\form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList.php on line 134

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcmq1.png)

And when I dump the contact variable before assigning it to the form, it comes up as being an object:
[contact variable as an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzQKm.png)

This is my ContactType form:

```
`<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Contact;
use App\Entity\Adherent;
use App\Entity\TypeVoie;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TelType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $typevoies = $options['typevoies'];
        $adherents = $options['adherents'];

        $builder
            ->add('politesse', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Politesse',
                'required' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'choices' => [
                    'Mr' => 'Mr',
                    'Mme' => 'Mme'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom',
                'constraints' => new Length([
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' =>  30
                ]),                    
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Merci de saisir le nom de contact"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('prenom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Prénom',
                'constraints' => new Length([
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' =>  30
                ]),                    
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Merci de saisir le prénom de contact"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('tel', TelType::class, [
                'label' => 'Téléphone',                   
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Merci de saisir le numero de téléphone"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('mobile', TelType::class, [
                'label' => 'Mobile',                   
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Merci de saisir le numero de mobile"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('mail', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Mail',                    
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Merci de saisir le mail"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('fonction', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Fonction',                    
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Merci de saisir la fonction"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('annule')
            ->add('numvoie', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Numero',                    
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Voie"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('typevoie', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Type de voie',
                'class' => TypeVoie::class,
                'choices' => $typevoies,
                'choice_label' => 'libelle',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Merci de choisir le type de voie"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('adresse1')
            ->add('adresse2')
            ->add('adresse3')
            ->add('postal')
            ->add('ville')
            ->add('adherent', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Adhérent',
                'class' => Adherent::class,
                'choices' => $adherents,
                'choice_label' => 'nom'
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Inserer',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success w-100'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Contact::class,
            'typevoies' => [],
            'adherents' => []
        ]);
    }
}`
```

This is my ContactController:

```
`<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Contact;
use App\Entity\Adherent;
use App\Entity\TypeVoie;
use App\Form\ContactType;
use App\Entity\Utilisateur;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class ContactController extends AbstractController
{
    private $entityManager;
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    #[Route('/administration/contacts', name: 'app_admin_contacts')]
    public function admin(): Response
    {
        $adherents = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Adherent::class)->findAll();
        $contacts = [];
        foreach ($adherents as $key => $adherent) {
            $contacts[] = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Contact::class)->contactsByAdherentId($adherent->getId());
        }  
        return $this->render('contact/index.html.twig', [
            'contacts' => $contacts,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/utilisateur/{user_id}/contacts', name: 'app_user_contacts')]
    public function user($user_id): Response
    {
        $loggedInUser = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Utilisateur::class)->find($user_id);
        if ($loggedInUser !== $user->getId()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
        }
        $association_id = $user->getAssociation()->getId();
        $adherents = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Adherent::class)->adherentsByAssocId($association_id);
        $contacts = [];
        foreach ($adherents as $key => $adherent) {
            $contacts[] = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Contact::class)->contactsByAdherentId($adherent->getId());
        }        
        return $this->render('contact/index.html.twig', [
            'contacts' => $contacts,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/contact/ajouter', name: 'app_add_contact')]
    public function add(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $associationId = $user->getAssociation()->getId();

        if ($associationId === 1) {
            $typevoies = $this->entityManager->getRepository(TypeVoie::class)->findAll();
            $adherents = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Adherent::class)->findAll();
        } 
        if ($associationId > 1) {
            $typevoies = $this->entityManager->getRepository(TypeVoie::class)->typevoiesByAssocId($associationId);
            $adherents = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Adherent::class)->adherentsByAssocId($associationId);
        }
        $contact = new Contact();
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact, [
            'typevoies' => $typevoies,
            'adherents' => $adherents
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->entityManager->persist($contact);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            if ($user->getRoles() === 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_contacts');
            }
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_contacts', [
                'user_id' => $user->getId()
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render('contact/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/contact/modifier/{contactId}', name: 'app_edit_contact')]
    public function edit($contactId): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $associationId = $user->getAssociation()->getId();

        if ($associationId === 1) {
            $typevoies = $this->entityManager->getRepository(TypeVoie::class)->findAll();
            $adherents = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Adherent::class)->findAll();
        } 
        if ($associationId > 1) {
            $typevoies = $this->entityManager->getRepository(TypeVoie::class)->typevoiesByAssocId($associationId);
            $adherents = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Adherent::class)->adherentsByAssocId($associationId);
        }

        $contact = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Contact::class)->findOneById($contactId);
        //dd($contact);
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact, [
            'typevoies' => $typevoies,
            'adherents' => $adherents
        ]);
        
        return $this->render('contact/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}`
```

And this is my Contact entity:

```
`<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ContactRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ContactRepository::class)]
class Contact
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 10)]
    private ?string $politesse = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 30)]
    private ?string $nom = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 40)]
    private ?string $prenom = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $tel = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $mobile = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $mail = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 40)]
    private ?string $fonction = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $annule = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 5, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $numvoie = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $typevoie = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $adresse1 = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $adresse2 = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $adresse3 = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 6)]
    private ?string $postal = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $ville = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'contacts')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Adherent $adherent = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPolitesse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->politesse;
    }

    public function setPolitesse(string $politesse): self
    {
        $this->politesse = $politesse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    public function setTel(?string $tel): self
    {
        $this->tel = $tel;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobile(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    public function setMobile(?string $mobile): self
    {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): self
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFonction(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fonction;
    }

    public function setFonction(string $fonction): self
    {
        $this->fonction = $fonction;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isAnnule(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->annule;
    }

    public function setAnnule(bool $annule): self
    {
        $this->annule = $annule;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumvoie(): ?string
    {
        return $this->numvoie;
    }

    public function setNumvoie(?string $numvoie): self
    {
        $this->numvoie = $numvoie;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTypevoie(): ?string
    {
        return $this->typevoie;
    }

    public function setTypevoie(?string $typevoie): self
    {
        $this->typevoie = $typevoie;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse1;
    }

    public function setAdresse1(string $adresse1): self
    {
        $this->adresse1 = $adresse1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse2;
    }

    public function setAdresse2(?string $adresse2): self
    {
        $this->adresse2 = $adresse2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse3(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse3;
    }

    public function setAdresse3(?string $adresse3): self
    {
        $this->adresse3 = $adresse3;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostal(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postal;
    }

    public function setPostal(string $postal): self
    {
        $this->postal = $postal;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVille(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    public function setVille(string $ville): self
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdherent(): ?Adherent
    {
        return $this->adherent;
    }

    public function setAdherent(?Adherent $adherent): self
    {
        $this->adherent = $adherent;

        return $this;
    }
}`
```

What is missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to resolve the issue by adding the following piece of the code to the form:

```
'multiple' => false,
'expanded' => false,
'mapped' => false
```

It has been added to 'typevoie' element of the form.

Comment: hey, 'mapped' => 'false' means that fiedl is not processed, so any changes (enter value, change value) just will be NOT PROCESSED

Answer (score 0):

worked for symfony 6.3, 6.4  Entitytype form field

**'query_builder' =>  MUST RETURN **QueryBuilder** OBJECT not real results**

solution:

```
->add('yourAnyField', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Your!!ANY!!EntityClassToFullFillSelectFormChoices::class,
    'query_builder' => function (YourEntityClassRepository $repo): QueryBuilder {
                    return  $repo->findGroupOptionsList(17);
                },

    'choice_label' => 'variableName',
    'choice_value' => 'id',


inject repository in FORMTYPE by constructor, 


repository MUST RETURN **QueryBuilder** OBJECT not real results 

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @return QueryBuilder
     */
    public function findByLinkUpstreamManyToOne($value): QueryBuilder
    {
        
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');

        return = $qb
            ->andWhere('m.linkUpstreamManyToOneEntityFieldName = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('m.id', 'ASC')
                ;

    }
```

note:

1. adding query into repository make it flexible, accessible by any service in the future
2. choice label is verry flexible callback function, you can generate "name" even from many ManyToOne sources [table levels]

   'choice_label' => function ($linkUpstreamMegaMenuSection) {
   return  '[menu] .$linkUpstreamMegaMenuSection->getLinkUpstreamMegaMenu()->getMegaMenuName().' | [section]  '
   .' '.$linkUpstreamMegaMenuSection->getSectionName();
   },

**I'm using own notation in entity for field names to describe relations in database** may it be also usefull for you

**linkUpstream**EntityCalled for ManyToOne  [A] <= [B,B,B,B]

**linkStream**EntityCalled for OneToMany  [A] => [B,B,B,B]

it gives me better view what data i'm looking at programing level